# Pytest case , generate multiple test cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest

I have to test multiple (5-6 test cases).I have an input folder where some files are there.I need to print them.

```
conftest.py
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--path_1", action="store", default="All",
    help="Please enter the path_1 which needs to be executed")    

@pytest.fixture
def path_1(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--path_1")

--------------------------------
test_t.py

import os,pytest

def test_1(path_1):
    print (path_1)
    list_files = list(set([f for f in os.listdir(path_1)]))
    print(list_files)
```

---

Run it as:

```
pytest -q -s -v --path_1="folder/" test_t.py
```

Comment: so you need to just print all files in a single run, or do you need each file as a parametrized input?

Comment: Each as parameterized input

Comment: There's no assertion in the test. If there's just printing, then pytest is not really needed.